# which jar file can be used to play an audio file in android

Tags: java, android, jar, media-player

When I was searching through google I found a java program created in netbeans to calculate the bpm of a song. It was working with a lot of JAR files.

I used the same code for my android app and it showed lot of errors due to the missing of only one JAR file. I added the JLayer1.0.1 jar file and all the errors were cleared.

Now the app is working good but the bpm calculation is creating some new problems. It gives the bpm of a song which is less than 1 min but the others songs are not always been in process for a hour. And the songs are not been played in the background.

When I checked with the Java program there it is calculating the bpm of all songs and the songs are been played and I can hear it.

What is the problem I am facing here? Is this all because of the JAR file, am I supposed to use any other JAR files? Please help me friends....

I am adding a part of my code

```
Player player = new Player(new FileInputStream("//sdcard//taxi.mp3"), output);

    public class BPM2SampleProcessor implements SampleProcessor {

        private Queue<Long> energyBuffer = new LinkedList<Long>();

        private int bufferLength = 43;

        private long sampleSize = 1024;
        private long frequency = 44100;
        private long samples = 0;
        private long beats = 0;
        private static int beatThreshold = 3;
        private int beatTriggers = 0;

        private List<Integer> bpmList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        public void process(long[] sample) {
            energyBuffer.offer(sample[0]);
            samples++;
            if(energyBuffer.size() > bufferLength) {
                energyBuffer.poll();
                double averageEnergy = 0;
                for(long l : energyBuffer)
                    averageEnergy += l;
                averageEnergy /= bufferLength;

                double C = 1.3; //a * variance + b;
                boolean beat = sample[0] > C * averageEnergy;
                if(beat)
                {
                    if(++beatTriggers == beatThreshold)
                        beats ++;
                }
                else
                {
                    beatTriggers = 0;
                }

                if(samples > frequency * 5 / sampleSize) {
                    bpmList.add(getInstantBPM());
                    beats = 0;
                    samples = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public void init(int freq, int channels) {
            frequency = freq;
        }


        public int getInstantBPM() {
            return (int)((beats * frequency * 60) / (samples * sampleSize));
        }

        public int getBPM() {
            Collections.sort(bpmList);
            return bpmList.get(bpmList.size() / 2);
        }

        public long getSampleSize() {
            return sampleSize;
        }

        public void setSampleSize(long sampleSize) {
            this.sampleSize = sampleSize;
        }

}

public class EnergyOutputAudioDevice extends BaseOutputAudioDevice {
    private int averageLength = 1024; // number of samples over which the average is calculated
    private Queue<Short> instantBuffer = new LinkedList<Short>();

    public EnergyOutputAudioDevice(SampleProcessor processor) {
        super(processor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void outputImpl(short[] samples, int offs, int len) throws JavaLayerException {
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
            instantBuffer.offer(samples[i]);

        while(instantBuffer.size()>averageLength*channels)
        {
            long energy = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<averageLength*channels; i++)
                energy += Math.pow(instantBuffer.poll(), 2);

            if(processor != null)
                processor.process(new long[] { energy });
        }
    }

    public int getAverageLength() {
        return averageLength;
    }

    public void setAverageLength(int averageLength) {
        this.averageLength = averageLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: "It gives the bpm of a song which is less than 1 min but the others songs are not always been in process for a hour. And the songs are not been played in the background." - what does this line in your question mean?

Comment: it means that it gives the bpm of the song which have durations around 1 to 2 min but not getting the songs which have duration of more than 2 min. Either it gets crashed or else detecting bpm for more than a hour. In the java code when the bpm will be showed when the song gets finished after playing, there i can hear the song but in android project i cant hear the song thats getting played

Comment: this is what i mean...........

Comment: Ok.. that makes it a lot clearer. Why don't you post the code?

Comment: are you sure that the songs on which your app is not working has BPM info check the songs in windows explorer using properties

Comment: i am not trying to get the bpm of a song from its header....

Comment: @TOX1C -> actually i also want to know the how to get the bpm from the header of an MP3 file in android...can u ls help me...